# Matlab Neural Networks using parallel toolbox

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to run the code from the documentation of Matlab on how to implement a neural network using the parallel processing toolbox and I get the following error.

Error :

Error using trainlm (line 104)
Input states Xi is not a matrix or cell array.

Error in network/train (line 106)
[net,tr] = feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);

Code:

```
[x,t] = house_dataset;
net1 = feedforwardnet(10);
y = net2(x);
net2 = train(net1,x,t);
matlabpool open;
net2 = train(net1,x,t,'useParallel','yes');
matlabpool close;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2012a.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality was not added until R2012b, unfortunately!

http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/release-notes.html